# Spring. Реализация Oauth.2.0 для REST API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Как можно совместить базовую авторизацию(login+password) с авторизацией других сервисов(google, github, facebook) с применением Spring Boot и Spring Security? Информации очень много и уже не понимаю как правильно решить данную задачу. Буду благодарен за туториал или линк на материал.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-oauth2-login - пример того как можно с помощью Спринга сконфигурировать вход через Google, Facebook

Comment: Приведите пример в текстовом виде, а не по ссылке.

Comment: этот пример я находил) интересно как можно совместить вышеупомянутый пример с авторизацией на основе логина и пароля